# Android - Unwanted space underneath ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, space

I use a MainActivity with a container for my fragments.
The MainActivitie's XML contains a toolbar with the following code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/c_green"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:title="@string/app_name"
    android:contentInsetLeft="10dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="10dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

The problem is the following:
On all my fragments I have this unwanted extra space underneath the ActionBar as can be seen in the picture.

[image: Here you can clearly see the white space that is present everywhere in the app.]

When on a recyclerView you can see the CardViews slide underneath the whitespace. I guess there is something wrong with the ActionBar.
I tried to add padding 0dp and margin 0dp, but none of that changed anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have found that instead of using

```
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

in my fragments, using

```
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/myActionBar_height"
```

with

```
    <dimen name="myActionBar_height">48dp</dimen>
```

fixed the extra space.
However I don't find this a good solution.

The problem seems to be an extra 10dp of margin top.